# Java LWJGL OpenGL Exception Access Violation 0xc0000005

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I get an error when glDrawElements() is called and I can't figure out why :/ I'm new to using OpenGL and I'm trying to learn how it works.

Note: I am using this library for turning an OBJ file into arrays that OpenGL should be able to use: https://github.com/korre/java-obj-to-opengl/blob/master/MeshObjectLoader.java

```
public class Mesh {

    private int vaoId;

    private List<Integer> vboIdList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private float scale = 1;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Vector3f position = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Vector3f rotation = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String textureKey;

    private int vertexCount;

    private Mesh(MeshObjectLoader.MeshArrays meshArrays) {
        vaoId = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

        var vboId = 0;
        vertexCount = meshArrays.getNumVertices();

        // Load vertices
        vboId = glGenBuffers();
        vboIdList.add(vboId);
        var vertexBuffer = (FloatBuffer) meshArrays.getVertices();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0 ,0);

        // Load texture coordinates
        vboId = glGenBuffers();
        vboIdList.add(vboId);
        var textureCoordsBuffer = (FloatBuffer) meshArrays.getTexCoords();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordsBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        // Clean everything up
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public static Mesh loadFromObjFile(String resourcePath) throws IOException {
        try (var resourceStream = Mesh.class.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath)) {
            return new Mesh(MeshObjectLoader.loadModelMeshFromStream(resourceStream));
        }
    }

    public void render(int textureId) {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

        glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        for (int vboId : vboIdList) {
            glDeleteBuffers(vboId);
        }

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(vaoId);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the crash is that you never bind a buffer object to the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding point of the VAO, so the last argument of `glDrawElements(..., 0)` is interpreted as a host-address pointer instead of an byte-offset in any element array buffer.
And dereferencing the `0` address fails, of course.

Whenever you call an indexed draw call like `glDrawElements` you also need an element array buffer (also called "index buffer").

The library returns the list of positions, texture coordinates and normals in such a way that you merely need to do a non-indexed draw call via `glDrawArrays()`. This is also pretty typical of a Wavefront OBJ loader, because the Wavefront OBJ format has separate indexes for positions, normals and texture coordinates, so a typical load will do the cross-product of all face indexes anyways and provide you with a linear/duplicated list of vertex data.

So: Do `glDrawArrays` instead.

Comment: The library (obj to opengl lib) doesn't seem to return a list of indexes. Is their a different draw method or some logic I'm missing here?